# Passing value from database to ComboBox

Tags: java, database, combobox

I am assigning my combobox to handle the Value or the Car Name so i make this code and NullPointerException is always the error does my code is wrong?

```
 public CarRent() 
{
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    try
    {
     AddItem();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }




}


public void Conn() throws Exception
{

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conn1,user,pass);   

}

public void AddItem() throws Exception
{
            String s = "Select Car_Name from Car_Tbl";
            rs = st.executeQuery(s);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(cboCars);
                cboCars.addItem(rs.getString("Car_Name"));
            }



}
```

> run:
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at trypo.CarRent.AddItem(CarRent.java:77)
>               at trypo.CarRent.(CarRent.java:50)
>               at trypo.CarRent$4.run(CarRent.java:413)
>               at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
>               at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
>               at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
>               at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
>               at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>               at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>               at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
>       BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: post the full error and tell us the line where your error occured

Comment: and also please post the stack trace.

Comment: @shampoo did you initialize `cboCars` ?

Comment: @shampoo put a `System.out.println(cboCars);` before `cboCars.addItem(rs.getString(1));` and tell the output

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Resultset rs = st.executeQuery(s)
 While(rs.next())
{
 cboCars.addItem(rs.getString("Car_Name");
}
```

Your rs variable needs to be initialized as a ResultSet.

I also don't know your code above the try.
Should be Statement

```
Statement st = null;
String s = "Select Car_Name from Car_Tbl";
```

After you populated the array cboCars.

```
JComboBox carList = new JComboBox(cboCars);
```

.....

```
Statement stmt = null;
String q = "select Car_Name from Car_Tbl"
String[] cars ;
int i = 0;
try { 
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()) {
    cars[i] = rs.getString("Car_Name");
    i++;
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    }finally{
     if(stmt !=null) { stmt.close();}
   }
}
// Now You have an array populated with cars . Create your combo box with the data

JComboBox carList = new JComboBox(cars);
```

Comment: it should be ..otherwise he/she should get a compile error not a nullpointer exception

Comment: instead of rs.getString(1) should try the name of the variable in the table. Also curios to see the code to intialize the cboBox

Comment: same problem with this sir

Comment: what do you mean @Joey

Comment: @shampoo You're using a JComboBox right? You should add the strings from the query to an array that is used to create the ComboBox.

Comment: the code for InitComponents()? and also rs ins't declared. Needs to be Resultset rs  in the code above

Comment: i do not have any idea where to put the method in comboBox since i am using C# it has a windows_load i think it is similar to that hehe isnt it? where should i put the method sir?

Comment: i declared it in the top ResultSet rs = null;

Comment: no i mean i am using C# before since i lerp to Java now i didnt have idea where to put a method that i created. i am using netbeans right now

Comment: Just add all the strings from the Database call to an array. Then create the combo box like the bottom of my answer using that array.